# 2 TextViews filling up remaining space equally

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make the following layout for a list item in ListView. Ideally I would want a layout with 5 text views arranged as follows:
Basically in the upper row I want two TextViews on each end to be fixed width while the other two equally split the remaining space. I have found suggestions on how to make one textview fill remaining space but nothing on how two textviews can evenly split space. The resulting set of five TextViews should fill the Layout item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="6dip">

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/s1"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height = "50dip"
        android:text="what"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="left"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/t1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "50dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/s1"
        android:text="why"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/t2"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "50dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/t1"
        android:text="why"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/s2"
         android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height = "50dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/t2"
        android:text="what"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        />
    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/bottom"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/s1"
        android:text="what"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does your `s1` and `s2` views will always have static width (50dip)? If yes - it will be possible to achieve what you need with only `RelativeLayout` with any additional `LinearLayout`s :)

Comment: LinearLayout with weights

Comment: Can you maybe draw something to give an idea of what you mean? It's a little hard to understand by reading. An image would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Replace parent `RelativeLayout` with `LinearLayout` (or if you can't add additional `LinearLayout` and put all `TextViews` into it then add `android:layout_weight="1"` to all `TextViews` you want to occupy equal portion of  remaining space.

Comment: This will do nothing on a RelativeLayout

Comment: That's correct. I did not checked type of root layout, Corrected

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:padding="6dip">

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/s1"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height = "50dip"
    android:text="what"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="left" />

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/s2"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height = "50dip"
    android:text="what"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/s1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/s2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:text="why"/>

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/t2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:text="why" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/s1"
    android:text="what"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```